How to switch 1-gang outlet box that has 2 switches to 2 1-gang outlet boxes?
I have this 1-gang outlet box that has 2 switches and there is not enough space for a 2-gang box. How do I split this box into 2 1-gang boxes?
Is it something an amateur can do safely? I'm thinking I can cut the drywall above the existing outlet and install the new box and run the wire of 1 of the switches through there?
Also can I replace the metal box with this plastic box?
The plastic box is deeper vs the metal one which only ~1.5" deep



Why switch to plastic? Metal has a bunch of advantages, including automagically grounding switches. Metal boxes are available in many different sizes.

I see that "23" on the escutcheon.  is this a commercial building?

looks like almost enough space for a 2 gang box.

The big, yet unasked question is , Why do you need to modify what you have?  Perhaps there is another solution other than bigger or additional boxes.

Hi all, I will go get metal boxes. This is single-family home, not a commercial building. The number is corresponding to the switch # on the main switchboard so I can easily identify which one to switch off.
I want to switch to smart switches which currently doesn't fit 2 switches into one 1-gang box

Whether it can be done safely by an amateur depends entirely on the amateur in question doing the job safely, or not. It can also depend on the occupancy and location, as some LAHJs prohibit homeowners from working on their own homes, and most prohibit renters or occupants including owners of shared buildings (Multiple Dwelling Units) from doing so, due to greater risk to the lives of others from mistakes. Places that allow homeowners to do work may or may not require passing some sort of test before permitting the work to commence.
I'll note that identifying and turning off the circuit (or circuits) was not in your list of steps, and really should be.
Replacing a metal box with plastic is a downgrade. You can get metal boxes 2-1/8" or 3-1/2" deep if you want a deeper box or need more cubic inches for box fill.
Other than that, if you cut the drywall neatly or are good at repairing drywall then it's fairly straightforward to do the job correctly. But it may be somewhat more complex to manage than you think, depending how the current wiring is arranged. for instance, current codes require bringing neutral to the switch box, even if the switch you are currently using does not need neutral. That may require extensive rewiring if the present switches are configured with a switch loop and have no neutral. Since you will be adding a new box, you are going to have to meet present applicable code in that new box, at least. You may also find that you need to extend the wiring for the present box if it runs through the space where you intend to put the new box.
